# Manually assign value to formgroup vs patchValue

Tags: angular

Assume I had the following form group:

```
this.cvForm = this._fb.group({
      name: ['', [Validators.required]],
      lastname: ['', [Validators.required]],
      nested: this._fb.group({
        level1: this._fb.group({
          level2: this._fb.group({
            checkbox: [this.checkbox, Validators.required] // this.checkbox is boolean value (initial value = false)
          })
        }),
      }),
    });
```

And then I assign the checkbox value to true (`this.checkbox = true;`).

---

When I assign manually to the form group without using `patchValue`:

`this.cvForm.value.nested.level1.level2.checkbox = this.checkbox;`

and observe the value: `console.log('a',this.cvForm.value.nested.level1.level2.checkbox) // return true`

It returns true but the checkbox wasn't checked.

But when I use `patchValue`:

```
this.cvForm.patchValue({
      nested: {
        level1: {
          level2: {
            checkbox:  this.checkbox
          }
        }
      }
    });
```

and observe the value: `console.log('b',this.cvForm.value.nested.level1.level2.checkbox) // return true`

It returns true and the checkbox was checked.

---

From [`patchValue()`](https://angular.io/api/forms/FormGroup#patchvalue) docs:

> Patches the value of the FormGroup. It accepts an object with control
>   names as keys, and does its best to match the values to the correct
>   controls in the group.

Does this mean when you manually assign the value it wouldn't reflect to the form as `patchValue` does? What is the difference between the two?

<kbd>**[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-test-patchvalue?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)**</kbd>

Comment: you can not asign manually the value changing this.cvForm.value..., you must use **getValue** and **setValue**, else the input has no update the values, touch, or even the value you see. Correct `this.cvForm.get('nested.level1.level2.checkbox').setValue(this.checkbox)` in general you use pathValue if you want to change severals formControls of the formGroup, and setValue if you want change the entire formGroup or only one FormControl

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because `patchValue`(just like `setValue`) does a little more work under the hood.

#### [patchValue](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1076-L1083)

```js
// For a `FormControl` instance
patchValue(value: any, options: {
  onlySelf?: boolean,
  emitEvent?: boolean,
  emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
  emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
 } = {}): void {
  this.setValue(value, options);
}
```

#### [setValue](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/model.ts#L1053-L1065)

```js
setValue(value: any, options: {
    onlySelf?: boolean,
    emitEvent?: boolean,
    emitModelToViewChange?: boolean,
    emitViewToModelChange?: boolean
  } = {}): void {
    (this as{value: any}).value = this._pendingValue = value;
    if (this._onChange.length && options.emitModelToViewChange !== false) {
      this._onChange.forEach(
          (changeFn) => changeFn(this.value, options.emitViewToModelChange !== false));
    }
    this.updateValueAndValidity(options);
  }
```

Where `onChange` function will look like [this](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/shared.ts#L110-L118)

```js
function setUpModelChangePipeline(control: FormControl, dir: NgControl): void {
  control.registerOnChange((newValue: any, emitModelEvent: boolean) => {
    // control -> view
    dir.valueAccessor !.writeValue(newValue);

    // control -> ngModel
    if (emitModelEvent) dir.viewToModelUpdate(newValue);
  });
}
```

`dir.valueAccessor !.writeValue(newValue);` is what reflects the **change** of the **model**(e.g: `FormControl`) into the **view**(a DOM element).

[`CheckboxValueAccessor.writeValue`](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/packages/forms/src/directives/checkbox_value_accessor.ts#L68-L70)

```js
writeValue(value: any): void {
  this._renderer.setProperty(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'checked', value);
}
```

I've recently written an article ["A thorough exploration of Angular Forms"](https://dev.to/angular/a-thorough-exploration-of-angular-forms-21pi) in which I try to explain how all things are set up when using forms.